# RAML: example vs examples

Tags: mule, raml, anypoint-platform

While doing Walkthrough 3-3 in mule 4 developer training, I am unable to understand why RAML facet examples works but example doesn't.

Environment: Anypoint-Design Centre - API Designer RAML 1.0

Errors : "Error: should have required property 'code' should have required property 'departureDate' should have required property 'destination' should have required property 'emptySeats' should have required property 'origin' should have required property 'price' "

This is the relevant extract from REST API RAML spec.

```
   /{ID}:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: AmericanFlight
              example:
                output: !include examples/AmericanFlightExample.raml
```

But if I change example to examples it works. Since the uri is expected to retrieve one and not many, I am under the impression facet = "example:" is correct. Also, for using facet= "examples:"  I would think the response should be an array (type: AmericanFlight[]) and the example raml to include multiple items. Following is the example raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
value:
    ID: 1 
    code: ER38sd
    price: 400
    departureDate: 2017/07/26
    origin: CLE
    destination: SFO
    emptySeats: 0
    plane: 
      type: Boeing 737
      totalSeats: 150
```

Can someone help me understand why this is so?

Comment: Share what you modified and what are the errors. Just saying that it has errors without providing details is not useful to understand the problem. Remember that in Stackoverflow you are expected to provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Quoting from my Q "I get multiple errors stating required property missing"  if I use facet = "example:" . No errors if I use facet= "examples:"

Comment: You should provide the verbatim error messages. Please read [Why should I post complete errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) for details. Also the failing versions for reproduction as I mentioned before. This is all in Stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common confusion using RAML because of assuming the plural means multiples examples as an array and that NamedExample means something different.

- `example:` is for a single example where you just add or include the values of the properties. Only contains the values of the object's properties ([RAML 1.0 spec link](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#single-example)).
- `examples:` is for multiple examples as a `map`, where each key is the name of the example ([RAML 1.0 spec link](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#multiple-examples)). That means an array is not a valid type for this facet.

Note that in your example `value:` is the name of an example, not a property. As an example if you add a second example to that file it could have key `value2:`.

This confusion is so common that MuleSoft documentation has some pages to clarify [RAML examples](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-named-examples) and [common misconceptions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-common-problems-raml-10).

Comment: Thanks! I had read the specs. But did not understand. Your explanation is simpler!